# XSLT call template on a string with delimiter

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

My input xml is this

```
                <StepSchedule>
                    <StepRateEffectiveDate>20191204</StepRateEffectiveDate>
                    <StepRate>3.400000</StepRate>
                </StepSchedule>
                <StepSchedule>
                    <StepRateEffectiveDate>20200304</StepRateEffectiveDate>
                    <StepRate>2.250000</StepRate>
                </StepSchedule>
                <StepSchedule>
                    <StepRateEffectiveDate>20200604</StepRateEffectiveDate>
                    <StepRate>2.000000</StepRate>
                </StepSchedule>
                <StepSchedule>
                    <StepRateEffectiveDate>20201204</StepRateEffectiveDate>
                    <StepRate>1.510000</StepRate>
                </StepSchedule>
```

My xslt where I need to reformat the dates to a different format

```
  <xsl:call-template name="date-formatter">
    <xsl:with-param name="date" select="./*:StepSchedule/*:StepRateEffectiveDate" />
  </xsl:call-template>

  <xsl:template name="date-formatter">
    <xsl:param name="date" />
    <xsl:variable name="year" select="substring($date, 1, 4)" />
    <xsl:variable name="month" select="substring($date, 5, 2)" />
    <xsl:variable name="day" select="substring($date, 7, 2)" />
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($year,'-',$month,'-',$day,'T00:00:00')" />
  </xsl:template>
```

When I run the transformation I get the following error

`Transform terminated: 'Type check error.  In call to built-in function 'substring', expected type '{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}string?' for argument 1 ('$sourceString' in namespace '') but found more than one item.`

When the input only contains one StepSchedule node it works fine, the problem is when there is more than one.

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context. -- P.S. Your question is tagged `xslt-1.0` but the construct `*:element` requires XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Are you sure you are using an XSLT 1 processor? That error messsage pretty much sounds like coming from an XSLT 2 or 3 processor.

Answer (score 1):

The context is not really clear, but if you replace

```
  <xsl:call-template name="date-formatter">
    <xsl:with-param name="date" select="./*:StepSchedule/*:StepRateEffectiveDate" />
  </xsl:call-template>
```

by

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//StepRateEffectiveDate">
        <xsl:call-template name="date-formatter">
            <xsl:with-param name="date" select="."/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
```

it seems to work. I'm not sure what your XPath is trying to select.

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bET2rWP